# Is it possible to play a clip backwards in jwplayer?

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

Can jwplayer play a video clip backwards in normal or slow motion speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. JW Player does not have any ability to manipulate the video itself. JW Player doesn't actually "play" the video. It's just a steering script, sending the video to the browser's own native HTML5 ability, or invoking a Flash plugin if necessary. It provides its own overlays for things like controls, playlists, and advertising, but it doesn't "process" the video in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to change the playback rate to a negative number, but I am not sure how the performance would be.

You could try to modify my script for playback rate and make it negative?

https://github.com/emaxsaun/speed/